# Which one is correct? Or are they both correct? If so, please explain why

Tags: grammar

**Devin passed him, his shoulder skidding across the side of the smaller boy's head.**

**Devin passed him, and his shoulder skidded across the side of the smaller boy's head.**

Comment: "skidding" is not present tense. "Is skidding" would be present progressive, but that's not what your first sentence says.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, both are correct. They each mean the same thing. They even suggest the same sense of time. The choice is a stylistic one.

People speaking casually are more likely to use the second pattern (possibly a witness telling an authority figure about an incident). The first is slightly more crafted (possibly a novelist building out a vignette).